# Testcafe + React + Browserstack

Tags: reactjs, automated-tests, e2e-testing, browserstack, testcafe

I am trying to use `testcafe-react-selectors` in my TestCafé tests to make testing the react parts of my app easier. The tests run fine locally, but when I try to run them in the CI, the react parts don't work.

Example jsx:

```
export const Nametag = ({ url, title, subTitle, disabled, 
 showChooseAnother, chooseAnotherText, }) => (
   <div className={`MediaHotBar__element text--ellipsis ${disabled ? 
      'MediaHotBar__element--background' : ''}`}>
    <a className="text__link--no-underline" href={url} disabled={disabled} >
      {title}
    </a>
  <div className="text--detail text--gray-7">{ showChooseAnother ? 
    <ChooseAnother id={chooseAnotherText} /> : <span>{subTitle} 
    </span> }</div>
  </div>
);
```

Example test:

Test snippet:

```
test('Verifies a user can navigate to medias from an In Progress 
  test', async (t) => {

  const mediaName = 'AB Test Variant';

  await waitForReact();

  await t
    .click(abTestShowPage.getMediaLink(mediaName))
    .expect(mediaPage.title.textContent).contains(mediaName);
 });
```

Page object:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import { ReactSelector } from 'testcafe-react-selectors';

export default class ABTestShowPage {
  constructor() {
    this.mediaNametag = ReactSelector('Nametag');
  }

  getMediaLink(mediaName) {
    return this.mediaNametag.withText(mediaName).find('a');
  }
}
```

I'm pretty stumped about what could be going wrong. I was able to run things interactively in Browserstack, and the dom is identical to what it looks like locally. Worst case, I can get rid of the `testcafe-react-selectors` because all of the not-React-related stuff works just fine, but I'd really like to figure this out because it makes the tests much neater. Thanks!

EDIT: This is the TestCafé output for this:

```
1) The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.

   > | Selector([function])
     |   .withText('AB Test Variant')
     |   .find('a')

  Browser: Chrome 69.0.3497 / Mac OS X 10.13.6

     46 |
     47 |  await waitForReact();
     48 |
     49 |  await t
   > 50 |    .click(abTestShowPage.getMediaLink(mediaName))
     51 |    .expect(mediaPage.title.textContent).contains(mediaName);
     52 |});
     53 |

     at click
  (/usr/src/app/testcafe/tests/abTesting/abTestShow.js:50:6)
```

The other React test case that is failing looks like this:

```
1) AssertionError: expected null to deeply equal 'Draft'

  Browser: Chrome 69.0.3497 / Mac OS X 10.13.6

     71 |  await waitForReact();
     72 |  const testStatus = await
  abTestShowPage.statusBox.getReact(({ props }) => props.status);
     73 |
     74 |  await t
     75 |
  .expect(abTestShowPage.showPageTitleTxt.textContent).contains('Untitled
  A/B Test')
   > 76 |    .expect(testStatus).eql('Draft');
     77 |});
     78 |
     79 |test('Verify that a user can delete an A/B test', async (t)
  => {
     80 |  const deleteButton =
  abTestIndexPage.getDeleteButton('Delete This');
     81 |

     at eql
  (/usr/src/app/testcafe/tests/abTesting/abTestIndex.js:76:25)
```

Comment: Could you please share the TestCafe report from the Browserstack test session? Also, note that the default display resolution of Browserstack's virtual machines is 1024x768, and it's likely different from your regular display resolution. This can cause the problem if the layout of your page is adaptive.

Comment: Added the test output. I have also tried fiddling with our webpack settings based on this closed issue: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-react-selectors/issues/37 We're sadly on webpack 1 though, so I haven't been able to find a settings tweak that might resolve this. I'm not sure if the layout is the problem, because the elements are definitely on the page... they just aren't being selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We figured out a way around this. I don't know if it's the best way, but adding `displayName` to the react components gets around the minification. I couldn't figure out a way to get webpack and uglify to do this for us, since we're on webpack 1, but I'm now unblocked!